# RestFB instagram integration

Tags: java, instagram-api, restfb, instagram-graph-api

Does anyone has some experience with this?
I was trying to find some tutorial for basic operations at least, I found only RestFb java docs, which is not very descriptive.
What I need: getting Instagram user by Id, searching of posts / users by search word, getting users posts, managing posts (publish, unpublish),...

From what I got from the API documentation is that Instagram account is bound to a Facebook page and I need a user access token of the user that has some role at that page.

When I want to get a Facebook user I create a DefaultFacebookClient with the access token and call fatchObject, but what should I create when I want Instagram data?

Thanks very much for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you still need to get the Page object with facebookClient.fetchObject and then get the IgUser object with

```
IgUser igUser = page.getInstagramBusinessAccount();
```

keeping in mind that the fetchObject will have to list as parameter fields the Instagram fields as well (e.g., instagram_business_account), like for example:

```
Page page = facebookClient.fetchObject("fb_page_name", Page.class,
                Parameter.with("fields", "id, name, username, about, fan_count, engagement, talking_about_count, picture, website, instagram_business_account"));
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I still have some more.
First of all. What access token should I use? From what I understood from the documentation, I need a page access token to get the page, but I need a user access token of the user with the editor / admin role on that page. 
Or should I completely ignore page token and make the call with the user token?

Comment: I will probably answer my question. When I try to use the user token, I get an Outh exception, that I am trying to reach non existing field instagram_business_account. When I try to use the page access token, I geet the page, but the page.getInstagramBusinessAccount() return null. Maybe it is because I do not have even the basic for the account. I would say, that I will get at least the account id, but maybe not.

Comment: Have a look at:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637555/how-do-i-use-restfb-iguser-getbusinessdiscovery/53651954#53651954
I think it will answer your question.